# How do I import custom functions from relative paths in Python?

Tags: python

I have one project directory and three sub-folders as such:

```
Project
--V1
--V2
--Testing
```

V1 and V2 contain versions of the same code, and Testing contains scripts that run code from V1 and V2.

Lets say V1 and V2 each contain helper functions in a file called helper.py that take a value and does something to it as such:

```
Project
--V1
----helper.py
--V2
----helper.py
--Testing
```

helper.py

```
def someFunc(value):
    # do something w/ value
```

How can I import these functions into a python file inside Testing? I am trying to achieve something like the following, which does not work:

```
from ../V2.helper import someFunc
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work? What result are you getting?

Comment: It tells me it is an invalid import library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to make each folder a python module, by adding an `__init__.py` file to each one, like this:

```
Project
__init__.py
--V1
----helper.py
----__init__.py
--V2
----helper.py
----__init__.py
--Testing
--__init__.py
```

With this, you can make absolute imports in your scripts:

```
from Project.V2.helper import someFunc
```

Comment: I will try this, thanks! Does the init function register the dir with the python interpreter or something to that effect? Can you explain how this works?